# GAS onOpen() not running for copied spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet with a script that includes onOpen() which successfully creates some custom menus. When I copied the spreadsheet (and the bound script of course), the onOpen() no longer runs. I tried a few things I found from other postings of the same problem:

1. Revoke the new spreadsheet's authorization - can't because it does not show up in my account as an authorized app.
2. Manually create a trigger for when the doc opens - I get an error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again."
3. Copied the script file itself and renamed it.
4. Renamed the enclosing script project.
5. Renamed the enclosing spreadsheet.

So, none of these has worked. Anything else I can try, or is there a known problem on Google's side?

Thanks!

Comment: There have been several reports of this sort of problem since 3 Oct. (e.g. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67374469, https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765394) The issue seems to be at Google's end. Looks like we may have to wait it out.

Comment: I think Dean is probably right... I had the same problem about 5 hours ago, but now my onOpen functions (script menus, etc.) are working again. I also noticed issues with Google Drive (not able to create folders), but things work correctly for me now there too. I think Drive looks slightly different now, so I wonder if Google was rolling out an update and has now finished the update.

Answer (score -1):

I looked at the said [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36765394) and found that the problem stemmed from this line of code:

```
 DriveApp.getFileById(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId());
```

To make this work, I would suggest to enable the Drive API in `Resources -> Advanced Google Services`. It will also ask you to **enable Drive API in your Google Dev console**. Do this and let me know if it worked for you.